# Cipher riddle - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, cipher

Decode this chaotic mix of letters and symbols:

> XLEMFHIWOVNYRUDQCJPASGBTKZ !AEZF ,FQPVPRHH TMDD RG QVU  OUHIVJH FDJMVR
>   R WVKZ RS SEGLBIZHJMFTRXAVKNQPDWYCUO

Here is the computing version:

```
XLEMFHIWOVNYRUDQCJPASGBTKZ !AEZF ,FQPVPRHH TMDD RG QVU OUHIVJH FDJMVR R WVKZ RS SEGLBIZHJMFTRXAVKNQPDWYCUO
```

---

Now you got the cipher: **Who am I?**

---

#### EDIT:

Clues are more clear in this version.

> Decode this *chaotic* mix of letters and symbols:

---

> **XLEMFHIWOVNYRUDQCJPASGBTKZ** !AEZF ,FQPVPRHH TMDD RG QVU OUHIVJH FDJMVR R WVKZ RS **SEGLBIZHJMFTRXAVKNQPDWYCUO**

Comment: Have you seen [Code Puzzles: What Not to Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)? The example there seems very similar to the puzzle you give here.

Comment: I will take into account, thanks! However, there are more clues in my question than in the one of the example, it is just that people might realize about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> The Beatles

The message is:

> WE HAVE A YELLOW VEHICLE AND WE NEED SOMEBODY, HELP!

Solution:

> As [Tas and M Oehm noted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56957/42302) there are two full permutations of the alphabet starting and ending the text. Using a [chaocipher](http://www.dcode.fr/chao-cipher) with the first transposition "XLEMFHIWOVNYRUDQCJPASGBTKZ" as the left disk alphabet and the second one "SEGLBIZHJMFTRXAVKNQPDWYCUO" as the right disk alphabet, the middle text becomes "!PLEH ,YDOBEMOS DEEN EW DNA ELCIHEV WOLLEY A EVAH EW".  When this text is reversed we get the answer above.  The Beatles wrote songs with chorus lyrics "We all live in a yellow submarine" and "Help, I need somebody".

Comment: That is perfect, you got the cipher! Now, what is the answer to the riddle??

Comment: Well done! The Chaocipher was new to me. Oh, and I believe that the yellow vehicle is one for travelling underwater ...

Comment: Thanks for the hint @MOehm .  The chaocipher was new to me too.  Honestly I just searched for "chaos cipher" based on the clues and found it that way.

Comment: Learn something new every day. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Not a complete answer</sub>

The cipher appears to be a

> Vigenère cipher

because

> The first 26 letters of the phrase are all the letters in the alphabet, so this is likely the alphabet used for the cipher:
>  XLEMFHIWOVNYRUDQCJPASGBTKZ

Although the question mentions letters and symbols, there are really only two symbols and since

> The ones before the first symbol are the alphabet, it's likely the ones between the `!` and `,` potentially represent something as well.

Other observations:

> The most common letters in the text appear to be `R` and `V`, and there is a double `H` and double `D`. Because `R` stands alone and appears in words of two, it's likely it's `A` or `I`

Comment: These are good observations, but note that both the first and last word are permutations of the alphabet. Also, the two punctuation marks come after a space, so it's probable that the centre part, i.e. the real message is reversed.

Comment: @MOehm is completely ok, now you know there are two alphabets, one on the right and another on the left, figure out the type of cipher. There is still one more clue to guess the cipher type.